# need explanation of a batch code

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Can anyone help me explain what the below batch code is doing?

```
REM CLIENT: CRM_CI_M8626AABBQNBAM200030.1.5
SET name=%CLIENT%
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=_" %%a IN ("%name%" ) DO (
    SET name=%%a
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **CRM_CI_M8626AABBQNBAM200030.1.5** is in %CLIENT%, the code assigns **CRM** to %name%.

Answer (score 0):

Supose var name *CLIENT* value is "stackoverflow_the_best_web :-)"

After script execution the result is a environment var with name "*name*" and value "stackoverflow":

## EXECUTION

```
REM CLIENT: CRM_CI_M8626AABBQNBAM200030.1.5
SET name=stackoverflow_the_best_web :-)
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=_" %a IN ("stackoverflow_the_best_web :-)") DO (SET name=%a )
(SET name=stackoverflow )
```

## RESULT:

```
C:\Windows\system32>set name
name=stackoverflow
```